# Merge and group by keys to aggregate another key in a list of dicts?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following list of dicts:

```
dict_lst = [{'ecs_service': {'bedstock-service': 0.6071428571428571}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'petardeer': 0.671957671957672}}, {'approval': {'yes': 0.6507936507936508}}, {'ecs_service': {'bedstock-service': 0.6180555555555555}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'tesg6': 0.6888888888888888}}, {'ecs_service': {'tickly-service-2': 0.6696428571428571}}, {'ecs_service': {'chagan-service-2': 1.0}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'chagan': 0.875}}, {'ecs_service': {'thioantimoniate-service': 0.6956521739130435}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'pinfish': 0.7619047619047619}}, {'ecs_service': {'biliously-service': 0.6694677871148459}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'test-cluster-4': 0.6904761904761904}}, {'ecs_service': {'chagan-service': 0.8857142857142858}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'chagan': 1.0}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'bedstock': 0.6212121212121212}}, {'approval': {'yes': 0.6161616161616161}}, {'ecs_service': {'bedstock-service': 0.8113636363636364}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'test-cluster-4': 0.6024531024531025}}, {'approval': {'yes': 0.6161616161616161}}, {'ecs_service': {'chagan-service-2': 0.7430555555555555}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'chagan': 0.75}}, {'ecs_service': {'chagan-service-2': 0.968421052631579}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'chagan': 0.8631578947368421}}, {'ecs_service': {'tickly-service': 0.6761904761904761}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'test-cluster-4': 0.638095238095238}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'unsaturation': 0.6428571428571429}}, {'ecs_service': {'coracopectoral-service': 0.6558091031775243}}, {'ecs_service': {'chagan-service-2': 0.7113095238095237}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'chagan': 0.7380952380952381}}, {'ecs_service': {'chagan-service-2': 0.7183641975308642}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'chagan': 0.7407407407407408}}, {'ecs_service': {'chagan-service-2': 0.9185185185185185}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'chagan': 0.8444444444444446}}, {'ecs_service': {'biliously-service': 0.6078431372549019}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'hirsel': 0.642483660130719}}, {'ecs_service': {'coracopectoral-service-2': 0.6327972709551657}}, {'ecs_service': {'chagan-service-2': 0.6928763440860215}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'chagan': 0.7311827956989246}}, {'ecs_service': {'chagan-service-2': 0.6732142857142858}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'chagan': 0.7238095238095239}}, {'ecs_service': {'chagan-service-2': 0.8941176470588236}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'chagan': 0.8352941176470589}}, {'ecs_service': {'coracopectoral-service-2': 0.6192645074224021}}, {'ecs_service': {'chagan-service-2': 0.6575854700854701}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'chagan': 0.717948717948718}}, {'ecs_service': {'chagan-service-2': 0.6478174603174603}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'chagan': 0.7142857142857143}}, {'ecs_service': {'chagan-service-2': 0.6343085106382979}}, {'ecs_service': {'chagan-service-2': 0.6367753623188406}}, {'ecs_cluster': {'chagan': 0.7101449275362318}}, {'ecs_service': {'chagan-service-2': 0.6195987654320988}}]
```

And I want to aggregate the dicts in the following way:

Group by outermost keys, then on the inner ones and average the values.

Meaning that if I have 2 dicts in my list:

```
[{'ecs_service': {'bedstock-service': 0.6}},
    {'ecs_service': {'bedstock-service': 0.2}},
    {'ecs_service': {'bedstock-service': 0.9}}]
```

I would like to get:

```
{'ecs_service': {'bedstock-service': 0.57}}
```

And so on for other keys.

I am trying to do this using:

```
final = {}
for d in test:
    for k, v in d.items():
        temp = defaultdict(list)
        for l, p in v.items():
            temp[l].append(p)
        final[k] = temp
```

But I am getting only the last entries. Also I will be happy to see a best practice how to merge such dicts in a more elegant way. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
from statistics import mean

out = {}

for d in dict_lst:
    for k, v in d.items():
        for kk, vv in v.items():
            out.setdefault(k, {}).setdefault(kk, []).append(vv)

for k, v in out.items():
    for kk in v:
        v[kk] = round(mean(v[kk]), 2)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "ecs_service": {
        "bedstock-service": 0.68,
        "tickly-service-2": 0.67,
        "chagan-service-2": 0.75,
        "thioantimoniate-service": 0.7,
        "biliously-service": 0.64,
        "chagan-service": 0.89,
        "tickly-service": 0.68,
        "coracopectoral-service": 0.66,
        "coracopectoral-service-2": 0.63,
    },
    "ecs_cluster": {
        "petardeer": 0.67,
        "tesg6": 0.69,
        "chagan": 0.79,
        "pinfish": 0.76,
        "test-cluster-4": 0.64,
        "bedstock": 0.62,
        "unsaturation": 0.64,
        "hirsel": 0.64,
    },
    "approval": {"yes": 0.63},
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what was the issue with my solution and why did you use the ```setdefault``` twice? @andrej-kesely

Comment: @SteveS With the last `final[k] = temp` you have you're overwriting previous values with newly created `defaultdict`. I'm using `setdefault` twice because I'm grouping outer and inner keys.

Comment: I am trying to rebuild it as a dict comprehension, can you add a version of it?
@andrej-kesely?

Comment: I think 3 for loops won't be efficient.